# Running into SSL issues with python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm running into SSL issues when trying to work on queries with the GitHub API. Have anyone else seen this?

SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

If it matters, I'm not using virtualenv here. I'm using OSX.

Just unsure how to fix this rather than seeing the auth check to false. 
That seems more odd a bandaid than a resolution. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What library are you using to generate your http requests? What version of OS X?

Comment: I am using the requests library.
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: Sorry I forgot the version. I am on OS X 10.9.5
10.10 is available and I am going to try upgrading to see if that helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

Github removed SSL3 support just yesterday (Oct 16) due to a [recently revealed vulnerability](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.ca/2014/10/this-poodle-bites-exploiting-ssl-30.html). It is an extremely old protocol, try moving to TLS 1.x instead (are your system SSL libraries up-to-date?)

https://developer.github.com/changes/2014-10-16-removed-ssl-version-3-support-from-webhooks-and-services/

EDIT: Because this looks like an OpenSSL issue, I'd recommend you try upgrading using instructions [available here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126830/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-os-x)

Comment: Crazy, just yesterday huh? I'll give that a go. THanks